# Is there a function to remove word with a certain lenth?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So, I got excel sheets with bunch of words seperated with space bar blanks.
So the row goes like this:

```
excel write a sheep e shave shovel with no g life less f
...
...
```

My question is, is there a way to remove those certain lenth of words?
like, if I want to delete words with a length of 1, result should be like this :

```
excel write sheep shave shovel with no life less
...
...
```

I'm not familiar with VBA so, I want to ask if there is a way to do it with a fomular
Hope you guys can help me.

Thanks !

Comment: do you have a single word in each cell or several words in one cell ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Oh I forgot to tell. bunch of words in a single cell. So, I just use A column and lots of rows with different sets of words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a VBA User Defined Function:

```
Public Function ytrewq(s As String) As String
    Dim arr, a, temp As String
    arr = Split(s, " ")
    temp = ""
    For Each a In arr
        If Len(a) > 1 Then
            temp = temp & " " & a
        End If
    Next a
    
    ytrewq = Mid(temp, 2)
End Function
```

use it like:

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the UDF from Excel:

```
=myfunction(A1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

*(this can be used if your version of Excel does not support either `TEXTJOIN()` or `FILTERXML()`)*.

Comment: Thank you Gary's Student. It seems like I don't have TEXTJOIN, so I tried your one since you kindly explained how to do it from the scratch (although, it gives me some error while I use ytrewq for the function's name, so I had to change it). It worked perfectly. Thank you again!

Comment: @JeongInKim  If you have a specific question, I will try to answer it.

Answer (score 3):

If one has TEXTJOIN:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[string-length(.)>1]"))
```

[image]

If one does not have TEXTJOIN put this UDF in a module attached to the workbook:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

Using:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[string-length(.)>1]"))
```

Confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Hello Scott. Thank you for taking a time. I should take a time to use VBA and UDF module. And thank you for the TEXTJOIN module itself as well! Hope you have wonderful day.

Answer (score 2):

If `FILTERXML` and `TEXTJOIN` functions are available to you then you can use below formula assuming source data is in cell `A1`

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[string-length()>1]"))
```

For `FILTERXML` function you can refer below excellent reference:

[Excel - Extract substring(s) from string using FILTERXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml)

Comment: Thank you shrivallabha.redij for taking your time! unfourtunately I didn't have TEXTJOIN to use it. But I learnt about it right now. Thank you for your advice! Have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function Replace , but first use LEN to decide how long your text is and check where your replacements with FIND

Comment: Hi. Yes, but the problem is, words are in a single cell, so... I think it needs more jobs for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use first LEN to check the length of your text , use FIND to check where is the charcters inside the text
Than use REPLACE , to replace those with a new text .